# Usage of for loop?

Tags: ruby, for-loop, iterator

Most of the time when I see a `for` loop used in Ruby, the person who wrote it does not know Ruby well. Usually, it is much more readable when a `for` loop is replaced by an iterator taking a block such as `each`.

Is there any use-case where `for` cannot be easily rewritten by an iterator with a block, or there is an advantage in using `for`?

Is it true that `for` is faster than an iterator method because `for` is a keyword? What is the purpose of `for`?

Comment: +1 Good question.  I suspect the downvotes are from readers who use for loops exclusively, generally looping over an index.  Ah, we will never know.  Anyway, I look forward to reading the discussion.  I don't expect it to be closed as aspects of the question call for objective answers. Hmmm, maybe sawa figured he'd pick up nine points for each downvote...

Comment: Maybe I was right.  Votes to date: +6, -4.  Haven't seen that before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block syntax is generally preferred by Ruby community.

There is a small difference in variable scope while using `for` or `each`. 
Variable declared within a `for` loop will be available outside the loop, where as those within an `each` block are local to the block and will not be available outside it.

Comment: It's a variable-pollution issue; `for` pollutes the variable space needlessly.

Answer (score 4):

I saw the `for` loop a lot in Rails books 6-8 years before. But is not preferred anymore.

There is a difference in the scope of the iterator variable. Take the following example:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]

numbers.each do |n|
  # do nothing
end
begin
  puts n 
rescue Exception => e
  puts e.message
end

for n in numbers do 
  # do nothing
end
puts "still: #{n}"
```

That would have this output:

```
# undefined local variable or method `n' for main:Object
# still: 3
```

Comment: I've not used v1.8, but I understand that, before 1.9, `n` would be in scope after `numbers.each do |n|..end` if `n` were previously initialized (e.g., `n = 0`).  In any event, I'm sure sawa is aware of the scope difference, and is looking for any other advantage--if one exists--to using `for`.